# How to decode modbus frame to float value using Arduino code?

Tags: c++, arduino, modbus, rs485

Hello please I need your help, I am currently working on an emodbus project with arduino, I want to read the data from energy meter to the serial monitor on the arduino board,

I send for example the following frame of the arduino towards the meter to recover the value of the tension:
`01 03 00 12 00 02 64 0E`
in response from the counter to the arduino card I receive the following frame:
`01 03 04 43 54 19 9A 25 9C`
which must have the value: `212.1`

my problem is that i could not display on the serial monitor
how can i decode this frame with arduino code to get the true value

Comment: What is the format of the frame what is in what bytes give an example how ro interpret

Comment: @Codebreaker007 recieve frame is in 9 byte : 01 03 04 43 54 19 9A 25 9C  , i don't know if i answer you correctly

Comment: Yes I read that but never mind I'll give you an answer in some minutes.

Comment: @Codebreaker007 Thanks so Much actually I could decode the frame in the output,
but the problem I encountered is that sometimes I get the true value sometimes not, the problem is in the reception frame, sometimes I don't get it full

Answer (score 0):

Read here about the [modbus library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/ArduinoModbus/ArduinoModbus)

> Frame formats (This answers my question from the comment - you should have known that)
>
> A Modbus "frame" consists of an Application Data Unit (ADU), which
>   encapsulates a Protocol Data Unit (PDU):[10]
>
> ```
> ADU = Address + PDU + Error check,
> PDU = Function code + Data.
> ```
>
> The byte order for values in Modbus data frames is most significant
>   byte of a multi-byte value is sent before the others. All Modbus
>   variants use one of the following frame formats.[1] 
> Modbus RTU frame
>   format (primarily used on asynchronous serial data lines like
>   RS-485/EIA-485) 
> Name  Length (bits)   Function 
> Start  28  At least 3½
>   character times of silence (mark condition) 
> Address   8   Station
>   address 
> Function  8   Indicates the function code; e.g., read
>   coils/holding registers 
> Data  n × 8   Data + length will be filled
>   depending on the message type 
> CRC     16  Cyclic redundancy check 
> End     28
>     At least 3½ character times of silence between frames

Before using the library or building blocks from it [read the issues first](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoModbus/issues).
For the application to [emodbus go here](https://github.com/merlokk/SmartHome/tree/master/lib): Look into the files emodbus.h and emodbus.cpp and etools.h and etools.cpp

Comment: can you check my issue ? in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998226/arduino-modbus-frame-sometimes-correct-sometimes-not

Comment: Yes well i solve it with this code : ` while (RS485->available())
  {
    RS485->readBytes(data, 9);

    String data1 = String(data[3], HEX) + String(data[4], HEX) + String(data[5], HEX) + String(data[6], HEX);

    const char modbus_data[data1.length() + 1];
    data1.toCharArray(modbus_data, data1.length() + 1);
    union
    {
      uint32_t i;
      float f;
    } voltage;
    voltage.i = strtoul(modbus_data, NULL, 16);
`